# mediapipe pose: How to convert a flat row of normalized (x, y. z, v) values into NormalizedLandmarkList

Tags: mediapipe

I want to construct the `results.pose_landmarks` from a flat list of normalized x, y, z and visibility values. This will allow me to use the `mp_drawing.draw_landmarks api` to annotate the image.

The list was created from an earlier run of the mp.solutions.pose.Pose.Pose() call and stored as a row in a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your data in `dict` you can instantiate the `NormalizedLandmarkList` using the following code:

```py
# assuming your landmarks are in dict - this fills the array with example (!) landmarks
landmarks_dicts = [dict(x=0.4, y=0.2, z=-0.5, visibility=0.9) for i in range(33)]

# convert back to NormalizedLandmarkList
from mediapipe.framework.formats import landmark_pb2
landmarks_loaded = landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmarkList(landmark = landmarks_dicts)
```

`landmarks_loaded` can then be passed to `draw_landmarks()` (make sure that you have loaded all 33 landmarks, otherwise you will get an exception).
Also ensure your landmark fields are called `x,y,z,visibility` as these will be accessed during instantiation.

You can find a full example with actual data loaded from json string here: [example - GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/anion0278/4804d117d13fe198c80db5bd74f6ed4a).